# How to enable copy paste on disabled TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a two way data binding set up for Title Text box on win form as below:

```
txtTitle.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", Person, "Editable", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Unfortunately, when text is Disabled users can't copy the text. Is there any workaround to enabling the COPY/PASTE preserving two way data bind?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textbox control has a ReadOnly property which you can set to true. Binding should still be updated.

**Option 1: Create a class with NotifyPropertyChanged**

Create a class holding the data that will be bound:

```
public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string name;
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value; 
            if (PropertyChanged != null) 
                PropertyChanged(this, 
                                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public Book(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Create an instance of this class and bind it:

```
public Book TheBook { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TheBook = new Book("");
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", 
                                          TheBook,
                                          "Name",
                                          true,
                                          DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, 
                                          ""));
}
```

Change the property and it will update:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TheBook.Name = "Different";
}
```

**Option 2: Create a custom control to mask Enabled as ReadOnly**

Create the following custom control and use that for binding to Enabled:

```
public partial class DBTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool enabled;
    public new bool Enabled
    {
        get { return enabled; }
        set
        {
            enabled = value;
            base.Enabled = true;
            ReadOnly = !enabled;
        }
    }

    public DBTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Whenever that DBTextBox is set to Enabled = false it will make it ReadOnly instead.

Comment: This won't work, winform has been setup as two way data bind. Need to sync ReadOnly and Enable which is not possible as DataBinding doesn't support ReadOnly

Comment: @Myagdi I edited my code to reflect more on binding. Does this help?

Comment: @Measuring I tried this on my side and it looks to be working. I'll remove my suggestion as it doesn't look like it works when binding is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Override the Enable property, set a local flag, ignore user input when keys are pressed by filtering by the local flag. And set colors to fake that it's disabled.